# Neo4j - unable to connect with sample .NET hello world program

Tags: .net, neo4j, connection

I just downloaded the neo4j Desktop and was able to create a new graph instance and connect.

- Here is the connection message
  You are connected as user  `neo4j`
  to  `bolt://localhost:7687`
  Connection credentials are stored in your web browser.

[Connection message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnnPp.png)

I'm a .NET developer and tried to download the sample Hello Word from https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/drivers/get-started/.

However, below exceptions were thrown. Please help.

```
Neo4j.Driver.V1.ServiceUnavailableException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Failed after retried for 5 times in 30000ms. Make sure that your database is online and retry again.
  Source=Neo4j.Driver
  StackTrace:
   at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.ExponentialBackoffRetryLogic.Retry[T](Func`1 runTxFunc)
   at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Session.<>c__DisplayClass41_0`1.<RunTransaction>b__0()
   at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Logging.DriverLoggerUtil.TryExecute[T](IDriverLogger logger, Func`1 func, String message)
   at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Session.RunTransaction[T](AccessMode mode, Func`2 work, TransactionConfig txConfig)
   at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Session.WriteTransaction[T](Func`2 work, TransactionConfig txConfig)
   at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Session.WriteTransaction[T](Func`2 work)
   at HelloWorldExample.PrintGreeting(String message) in D:\AI\neo4j\TestNeo4j\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 21
   at HelloWorldExample.Main() in D:\AI\neo4j\TestNeo4j\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 42

Inner Exception 1:
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.

Inner Exception 2:
ServiceUnavailableException: Connection with the server breaks due to SecurityException: Failed to establish encrypted connection with server bolt://localhost:7687/.

Inner Exception 3:
SecurityException: Failed to establish encrypted connection with server bolt://localhost:7687/.

Inner Exception 4:
```

Comment: Hi. Have you tried what is suggested in docs? From docs of C# driver: "When this type of error happens, recreation of the driver might be required" (https://neo4j.com/docs/api/dotnet-driver/1.4/html/625fd7ff-9b29-5aa7-4607-ba05abbc004a.htm )

Comment: Can you please confirm what version of Neo4j and the .NET drivers you are using

Comment: Neo4j is v4.0.0 and .NET Neo4j.Driver is v1.7.2. However, I'm able to connect to Neo4j sandbox sample project. It seems some configs are not set properly in my local neo4j instance.

Comment: I tried (neo4j.com/docs/api/dotnet-driver/1.4/html/… ), but didn't work